# (Android) Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor request failed)

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, android, adb

So I'm trying to connect my Xiaomi mobile with Windows 8.1 pc to unlock bootloader.

I get error every time I connect phone Device not recognised.
Device manager shows **Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor request failed Code 43)**.

What I have tried:
Tried to install drivers from OEM as well as from Google.
Updating Drivers and running Troubleshooter.
Tried almost every tutorial that is supposed to fix this problem. All methods EVERYTHING.

I think (not sure) "Requesting Device Descriptor Failed" means Windows is not able to get "Description" of device so not able to install drivers accordingly.

OR is there fault in data cable that might be causing this. But I don't have any as of now.

I'm not sure what to do.

Can you provide me some direction to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to resolve the driver issue:

1. I suggest you download and install ADB and Fastboot drivers from the web. There are plenty available.
2. Always use a good quality micro USB cable to connect your device to PC.

Unlocking the boot loader of Xiaomi phones is a pain in itseld even without these driver issues.
please follow the below video to successfully unlock the bootloader of your phone.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUAblsw2JgU

Cheers!

Comment: I think we should not unlock OEM to just fix the error